# Use linear projection without constant to obtain the linear projection with constant

Tags: mathematical-statistics, linear-model

We know that the linear projection of $y$ on $x_0$ $x_1$, $x_2$, . . . $x_K$ always exists and is unique:

$$L(y|x)= \gamma_0 x_0 + \gamma_1 x_1 + ... + \gamma_k x_k = x\gamma$$

where $x = (x_0, x_1, ..., x_K)$ is a $1\times(k+1)$ vector and $\gamma = (E[x'x])^{-1}E[x'y]$.

Using this fact directly, how can I conclude that the linear projection of $y$ on $1$,$x_1$, $x_2$, . . . $x_K$ is

$$L(y|x)= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + ... + \beta_k x_k = \beta_0 + x\beta$$

where $x = (x_1, ..., x_K)$ and

1. $\beta = [Var(x)]^{-1}Cov(x,y)$
2. $\beta_0 = E(y) - E(x)\beta$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll substitute $x_0=1$ in the given equations. First let $x=[1 \ \ \mathcal{u}]$, where $u=[x_1 \ x_2 \ ... \ x_k]$, and $\gamma=[\beta_0 \ \ \beta]'$. Then the solution equation becomes:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & E[u] \\ E[u'] & E[u'u]\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\beta_0 \\ \beta\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}E[y] \\ E[u'y]\end{bmatrix}$$

The first equation yields $\beta_0+E[u]\beta=E[y]$, which is (2). (Just replace $u$ with $x$). The second equation is:
$$E[u']\beta_0+E[u'u]\beta=E[u'y]$$
When we substitute $\beta_0$:
$$E[u']E[y]-E[u']E[u]\beta+E[u'u]\beta=E[u'y]$$
$$(E[u'u]-E[u']E[u])\beta=E[u'y]-E[u']E[y]$$
$$\operatorname{Var}(u)\beta=\operatorname{Cov}(u,y)\rightarrow \beta=\operatorname{Var}(u)^{-1}\operatorname{Cov}(u,y)$$